# Line breaks in the vscode terminal output, disturbing the view. when used more than 6 elements in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, visual-studio-code

Line breaks in the Vscode terminal output, disturbing the view. when more than 6 elements are in an array.

```
const a1 = [2,14,4,3,6,9]

console.log(a1)
```

**Results (Console):**

```
[ 2, 14, 4, 3, 6, 9 ]
```

**BUT**

If I use ONE more element in this array, like this:

```
const a1 = [2,14,4,3,6,9,10]

console.log(a1)
```

I get this:

```
[

  2, 14,  4, 3,
  6,  9, 10

]
```

I expected straight lines to come out without line breaks, to see clean results. How do I fix this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert array to string by join the items on the basis of ',' and the display for the consistency purpose

```js
const a1 = [2, 14, 4, 3, 6, 9, 10];
console.log(`[ ${a1.join(', ')} ]`);
```